# Cups line printer skip page after printing one line

Tags: linux, printer, cups, lpr

I have a cups line printer (Epson 9 pin).Printing works fine but it skips the page after one print.

I'm using `echo "Hi" | lpr -P myprinter` command to test.

It prints the message,But when I again print using this command, it skips the current page and print on the next page(Obviously there is lot of space in current page). Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the switch `l` fixed the issue.

```
echo "Hi" | lpr -l -P myprinter
```

`-l`
           Switch     Specifies that the print file is already formatted for the destination and should be sent without filtering. This option is equivalent to "-o raw".

Answer (score 0):

The `CUPS` printer server considers everything that you send it as a separate printer job.  This means, your line containing "Hi" is a printer job.  By default, different printer jobs go to different pages; this explains what you are now getting.

Now, 30 years ago when all printers were like your Epson 9pin, things were different.  Printer managers like `CUPS` were seldom used.  It was very common to send data to the printer one line at a time, like you do with your `echo`, and it was natural for the printer to wait for the next line, without going to the next page.  This is how we used to print stuff.  If you want to do that now, you'll have to print using "RAW" mode, practically bypassing the printer job management that CUPS performs.  You'll also need to suppress the "form feed" that CUPS by default sends in between printer jobs, which causes the page change; you'll need to print a final "form feed" yourself.

I suggest that you take a look [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/printing-form-feed-suppression-help-173707341.html), you may find your answer already waiting.